# Setting environment variable in /usr/bin/env hangs process on Linux

Tags: linux, shell, shebang

While the man for `env` on Linux seems to indicate that you can set new environment variables before executing a command. Unfortunately, when I set new variables in a file's shebang on Linux systems, the file never executes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env VAR1=foo bash
echo $VAR1
```

When I execute this file on a CentOS or Ubuntu machine, it just sits there.

```
$ ./shell-env.sh
<nothing happens>
```

What I find particularly bizarre is this works perfectly fine on OS X with BSD `env`.

```
$ ./shell-env.sh
foo
$
```

Is this just a difference between BSD `env` and Linux `env`? Why do the man pages for Linux seem to say it should work the same way as on BSD?

P.S. My use case here is to override the `PATH` variable, so I can try to find a `ruby` on the system but that's not on the `PATH`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you redefining the `PATH`? If so, does your new PATH include `bash`?

Comment: You can use `env` to set a variable before executing a command _from the command line_, but not in the shebang on Linux.

Comment: This Q **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related site http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux). Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Comment: I don't understand, why no just set `PATH` from within the script?

Comment: The rules for the sheebang line on, say, Linux say that exactly one argument is used. Hence, `env` gets as only argument `VAR1=foo`, but never sees `bash`. It's interesting to know that BSD is doing this differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a way to manipulate the environment before executing a Ruby script, without using a wrapper script of some kind, but it's not pretty:

```
#!/bin/bash
export FOO=bar
exec ruby -x "$0" "$@"

#!ruby
puts ENV['FOO']
```

This is usually reserved for esoteric situations where you need to manipulate e.g. `PATH` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before executing the program, and it needs to be self-contained for some reason. It works for Perl and possibly others too!

Comment: This is amazing, thank you! It was exactly what I was looking for.